# Почему после одноразовой смены текста цвета вывода echo, цвет меняется на весь скрипт

Tags: linux, bash

Допустим есть скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
apt update -y
echo -e "\033[31mОбновление выполнено"
apt upgrade -y
```

Сначала идёть стандартный вывод логов обновления из команды `apt update -y` затем красным цветом выводиться `Обновление выполнено` но затем идёт вывод команды `apt upgrade -y` но почему-то вывод логов идёт полностью красным цветом. Вопрос почему текст логов команды `apt upgrade -y` красного цвета и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает верно, так и должно быть. Про цвета в консольных программах вы можете почитать подробнее вот здесь: [habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/119436/)

Вам просто необходимо повторно задать нужный вам цевет после завершение работы программы. Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt update -y
echo -e "\033[31mОбновление выполнено"
echo "\033[0m" #возвращаем все цвета по умолчанию.
apt upgrade -y
```

[если мой ответ вам помог, то проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный]

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть стандартный поток вывода, который имеет некоторое состояние. Можно упрощенно представить, что туда можно записать как данные, так и "команды"(`Escape Sequences`). Эти команды меняют состояние потока вывода, а не форматируют конкретную строку, с которой они передаются. Таким образом, чтобы изменить состояние потока, ему надо опять дать команду, например, сброс стилей и цветов(`[0m`).